React Native Top Navigator, Tab screen not rendering with one screen
I have a nested top navigator that dynamically grows as I add days to a routine.
Starting from zero, after you add the first day the screen isn't rendered, only after adding the second screen, and scrolling to the second screen, the second screen is rendered and I can scroll back to the first and it is rendered. Note: I also can open up routines that are already filled with days and all screens render fine on the first try.
I tested just putting a Text view in the Day Scream component and trying to add one day but still nothing renders.
Been looking at it for a few hours and can't find what's wrong.
Where I add days to the Tab Navigator
<TouchableOpacity style={style.closeButton} onPress={() => {
                            const newObj = { ...splitDays, [dayName]: [] }
                            setSplitDays(newObj);
                            setDays([...days, dayName.toString()]);

                            setdayName("");
                            setaddDayModal(false);

                        }}>

<Tab.Navigator
                tabBarOptions={{
                    activeTintColor: '#000000',
                    indicatorStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: '#5D4DE4',
                    },
                    tabBarLabelStyle: {
                        fontFamily: 'nunito'
                    },

                }}
                screenOptions={{
                    tabBarScrollEnabled: true,

                }}

            >
                {
                    days.length != 0 ?
                        <>
                            {
                                days.map((day) => (
                                    // maps days to screens in the tab navigator
                                    // day is just the title and dayData is an array of exercies taken from split days
                                    <Tab.Screen name={day} key={day} component={DayScreen} initialParams={{ day: day, dayData: splitDays[day], setstaged: setstaged }} />
                                ))
                            }
                        </>
                        :
                        <Tab.Screen
                            name="Empty"
                            component={Text} />
                }
            </Tab.Navigator>

